# Refresh Coordinate Reference System in QGIS layers

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a large project where several files were loaded with its original CRS, not always the same.
To try to speed up my project, I recently converted all .shp files under the QGIS project directory to a single CRS using GDAL's ogr2ogr. Old files were overwritten.
When I check now the CRS in each layer in QGIS, the original CRS is shown.

Is there a way for QGIS to refresh the CRS of the layers?

I'm working with 2.14.14 version.

Comment: Can you share the output of ogrinfo of your layers ? Can you give more detail about your CRS translation

Comment: Layer name: Blocos_R14_v13
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2017-09-21
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 287
Extent: (-54.000000, -34.750000) - (-35.250000, -5.166667)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
nome_bacia: String (50.0)
nomenclatu: String (50.0)
indice_blo: Integer64 (10.0)
situacao_b: String (1.0)
nome_setor: String (50.0)
area_bloco: Real (24.3)
ID1: Integer64 (10.0)
</pre>

Comment: That is the result of ogrinfo for one layer. In Layer properties in QGIS is showing EPSG 4674 (original CRS when loaded in the project). I converted it using ogr2ogr -t_srs epsg:4326

Comment: Please edit your question not the comment

Comment: Do you saved a project file ? Can you save as ... Another possibility is to clear the cache

Comment: I saved the project with "save as". No refresh. Don't know how to clear the cache..